# I Keep Getting the error Message "missing Keyword"

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting the error message "missing keyword'. I don't know what it is I am missing, can anyone help?

here is my code

```
create trigger EmployeeforUpdate
after insert
on Employee
for insert, delete, Update
declare
  staff_id;
begin
insert into payroll
(first_name, middle_name, surname, department, designation, Grade_level,step)
select (first_name, middle_name, surname, department, designation, Grade_level,step)
from employee
End
/
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the select list.

Comment: staff_id data type?

Comment: @jarlh the staff_id data type is varchar

Comment: tried, still getting the same error message

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER EmployeeforUpdate AFTER INSERT
on Employee
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE staff_id VARCHAR(50);
INSERT INTO payroll(first_name, middle_name, surname, department, designation,Grade_level,step)
SELECT first_name, middle_name, surname, department, designation,Grade_level,step FROM employee
End;
```

More info about insert into select: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: I updated my answer. Notice the BEGIN command before the DECLARE command. I couldn't test it, because i don't have MySQL. Hope it works.

Comment: You also declare a variable staff_id, but did not set his datatype.

Comment: The syntax to declare a variable in MySQL is:
DECLARE variable_name datatype [ DEFAULT initial_value ]